# System of rules transformingn a multivariate polynomial onto corresponding partial derivative operator

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, operators

I take a complex multivariate polynomial, and I want to transform it into the corresponding differential operator. I.e., I am looking for the set of rules transforming variables to derivation, multiplication to composition, power to corresponding order derivation, and keeping addition and real coefficients
For instance, let

```
 (x + 2y*z + z^2) /. rules
```

gives a result the operator

```
(D[#, x] + 2D[#, y, z] + D[#, {x, 2}]) &
```

But how to find the functional rules? My intuitive attempts did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because of the mixed derivatives. But it can be done using `CoefficientList` and `Exponent`.

Here is your expression with a constant term added for generality:

```
expr = (3 + x + 2 y*z + z^2);
```

First we get the CoefficientList and the exponents:

```
cl = CoefficientList[expr, var]
el = Exponent[expr, var]
```

If you are not familiar with `CoefficientList`, you may need to look up the structure of cl in the help.

In the following we first use "DD" instead of "D" to prevent the activation of the derivatives. We first create the same structure that `CoefficientList` returns and insert the dummy "DD" command. Then we delete the non-derivatives and replace the dummy argument "arg" by "#". Finally we can multiply with the  structure from `CoefficientList`:

```
t = Array[DD[arg, Transpose[{var, {##} - 1}]] &, el + 1] ;
t = t /. {_, 0} :> Nothing /. DD[arg, {q___}] -> DD[#, q];
t = t cl;
```

Now we flatten our structure and sum the terms up and replace the non-derivative "DD[#]" by "#":

```
t = Total@Flatten@t;
t = t /. DD[#] -> #;
```

We now must transform our expression into a function and replace the dummy derivative by the real thing:

```
fun=With[{t = t}, t &] /. DD -> D
```

[image]

Comment: I think some of this can be made easier by the fact that zero-th derivatives are just fine in `D`.  That is, e.g., `D[f[x, y], {y, 0}]` evaluates to `f[x, y]`, and `D[f[x, y], {x, 1}, {y, 0}]` evaluates (as it should) to `Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like so.

```
derivationRules[e_] := Module[
  {vars = Variables[e], dD, rules, diffpoly},
  rules = 
   Table[vars[[j]]^n_. -> (dD[#, {vars[[j]], n}]), {j, Length@vars}];
  diffpoly = (ee /. rules);
  Function[Evaluate@diffpoly] /. dD -> D
  ]
```

Your example:

```
In[546]:= InputForm[
  derivationRules[x + 2 y*z + z^2]]

(* Out[546]//InputForm=
  D[#1, {x, 1}] +
  2*D[#1, {y, 1}]*D[#1, {z, 1}] +
  D[#1, {z, 2}] & *)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think there is a problem with mixed derivatives. A mixed derivative is not the product of the single variable derivatives.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHuber. I guess I should turn products into compositions. Turns out it's just easier to up-vote your answer though.